# Проблема во время выполенения запроса к Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, linux-mint

Система сборки: Gulp v3.9.1.

Операционная система: Linux Mint.

Во время выполнения каждого запроса, показывает эту ошибку:

> /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory

P.S:  Node.JS у меня установлен версии v4.2.6 .

---

Я уже решил проблему спасибо большое.Прошу закрыть тему.

Comment: код покажите, а то непонятно что у вас там